# How to draw a ring shape in Java using unit circle trig

Tags: java, loops, graphics, awt, trigonometry

I have to draw a ring using lines (`drawLine`) in Java that should look like the attached picture. We are provided with the class`DrawingPanel` that can be found [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwi6wuWvhfrbAhVkHjQIHSRIAVQQFggpMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.buildingjavaprograms.com%2FDrawingPanel.java&usg=AOvVaw3tNC_yR-eWpoHKNikQ8TtM).

I've made a regular circle using lines, but I'm unsure how to get the ring shape. I'm new to programming and this is my first post, so apologies if I've missed something important.

This is my code so far:

```
public static int panelSize = 400;
    public static void drawCircle()
    {
    double radius = 200;
    int x2 = 200;
    int y2 = 200;

    DrawingPanel dp = new DrawingPanel(panelSize, panelSize);
    dp.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

    Graphics dpGraphics = dp.getGraphics(); 
    dpGraphics.setColor(Color.RED);

    for (int circle = 0; circle <= 360; circle++)
    {
        int x = (int)(x2 + Math.sin(circle * (Math.PI / 180)) * radius);
        int y = (int)(y2 + Math.cos (circle * (Math.PI / 180)) * radius);

        dpGraphics.drawLine(x, y, x2, y2);
    }
}
```

This is what the final result should look like:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXInb.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a figure can be drawn by drawing a line from one point to a point farther away on the circle, passing the starting point several times.

This is what I came up with:

```
// Radius
int radius = 200;
// center of the circle
int centerX = 300, centerY = 300;

// The number of edges. Set to 5 for a pentagram
int mod = 136;
// The number of "points" to skip - set to 2 for a pentagram
int skip = 45;

// Precalculated multipier for sin/cos
double multi = skip * 2.0 * Math.PI / mod; 

// First point, calculated by hand
int x1 = centerX; // sin(0) = 0
int y1 = centerY + radius; // cos(0) == 1

for (int circle = 1; circle <= mod; circle++)
{
    // Calculate the end point of the line.
    int x2 = (int) (centerX + radius * Math.sin(circle * multi));
    int y2 = (int) (centerY + radius * Math.cos(circle * multi));
    dpGraphics.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    // Next start point for the line is the current end point
    x1 = x2;
    y1 = y2;
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Example code, overloaded java.swing.Frame.paint(java.awt.Graphics g)]

Comment: Thank you, I can't upvote you because I don't have 15 reputation yet, but I really appreciate the help.